# Logo and text on same line Officer R

Tags: r, officer

I need to place a logo on my document and have a text on the same line.

```
library(officer)
library(magrittr)

my_doc <- read_docx()

my_doc <- my_doc %>%
  body_add_fpar(fpar(ftext(
    paste0("Text"),
    fp_text( font.size = 16)),
    fp_p = fp_par(text.align = "right",shading.color = '#E8E8E8')), pos = 'on') 

my_doc <- my_doc %>%
  body_add_img('logo.png', width = 3, height = 0.9, pos = 'after')

my_doc <- my_doc %>%
  body_add_fpar(fpar(ftext(
    paste0("Text"),
    fp_text( font.size = 16)),
    fp_p = fp_par(text.align = "right",shading.color = '#E8E8E8')), pos = 'after') 
my_doc <- my_doc %>%
  body_add_fpar(fpar(ftext(
    paste0("Text"),
    fp_text( font.size = 16)),
    fp_p = fp_par(text.align = "right",shading.color = '#E8E8E8')), pos = 'after') 
my_doc <- my_doc %>%
  body_add_fpar(fpar(ftext(
    paste0("Text"),
    fp_text( font.size = 16)),
    fp_p = fp_par(text.align = "right",shading.color = '#E8E8E8')), pos = 'after') 

print(my_doc, target = 'file.docx')
```

Current result is:

[image]

Desired result is:

[image]

I tried to manipulate the position, tried to create some sort of 2 column layout.
No success...

Comment: an example is available here:  https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/paragraphs-chunks.html#fpar

Comment: I don't believe it is possible with that solution. The logo takes the entire line and all other text come after.
Is there an option to have the logo "In front of text" instead of the current "In line with text"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with a 2 columns section:

```
library(officer)
library(magrittr)

img.file <- file.path( R.home("doc"), "html", "logo.jpg" )

a_par <- fpar(
  external_img(src = img.file, height = 1.06/2, width = 1.39/2),
  fp_p = fp_par(text.align = "center", padding = 5))

b_par <- fpar(
  run_columnbreak(),
  "Text",
  run_linebreak(),
  "Text",
  run_linebreak(),
  "Text",
  run_linebreak(),
  "Text",
  run_linebreak(),
  "Text",
  run_linebreak(),
  fp_p = fp_par(text.align = "center", padding = 5))

doc_1 <- read_docx()

page_size <- docx_dim(doc_1)$page

bs <- block_section(prop_section(
  section_columns = section_columns(widths = c(3, 1), space = .1, sep = FALSE),
  page_size = page_size(width = page_size["width"], height = page_size["height"]),
  type = "continuous"))

doc_1 <- body_add_fpar(doc_1, value = a_par)
doc_1 <- body_add_fpar(doc_1, value = b_par)
doc_1 <- body_end_block_section(doc_1, bs)
doc_1 <- body_add_par(doc_1, value = "a new section", style = "Normal")

print(doc_1, target = tempfile(fileext = ".docx"))
```

[image]

Comment: Un grand merci. Will test and revert.

Comment: This works just perfect! Thanks a lot David.